# C# await演算子使わないコードでこの警告文は何を意味しているのか知りたい。

Tags: c#

提示コードの`Input.cs`の`public static async void setPlayList(string url)`関数ですが`await`してほしくなくまた`Data.cs`のコンストラクタ部でも`await`して実行を待機してほしくありません、しかし`visual studio`上で以下の警告が出ますこれはどうしてでしょうか？`await`は実行を待機するキーワードではないのでしょうか？

###### 警告

```
warning CS4014: この呼び出しを待たないため、現在のメソッドの実行は、呼び出しが完了するまで続行します。呼び出しの結果に 'await' 演算子を適用することを検討してください。

warning CS1998: この非同期メソッドには 'await' 演算子がないため、同期的に実行されます。'await' 演算子を使用して非ブロッキング API 呼び出しを待機するか、'await Task.Run(...)' を使用してバックグラウンドのスレッドに対して CPU 主体の処理を実行することを検討してください。
```

###### 知りたいこと

１，目的の動作は実装できたのですがこれは実装として正解なのか知りたい。
２，その場合`///`部で発生する上記の二つの警告文は無視していいのか知りたい
３，`Debug.WriteLine()`関数を使って処理を確認しました非同期で実行されているのですがなぜ同期処理という警告なのでしょうか？

###### 参考サイト

https://rksoftware.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/001-4/
https://qiita.com/mxProject/items/e2b2271fd26cfc8b059c

###### 環境

OS: windows10
IDE: Visual studio 2022
言語 C#
作成したプロジェクト windows form GUI
バージョン .Net 6.0

###### 試したこと

`Debug.WriteLine();`を利用して動作を確認しましたが非同期実行されているように見えます。

###### Input.cs

```cs
        /* ########################### プレイリストを設定 ###########################*/
        public static async void setPlayList(string url)　//warning CS1998
        {
            Action job = () =>
            {
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "yt-dlp";
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;            // コンソール・ウィンドウを開かない
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;          // シェル機能を使用しない
                //process.OutputDataReceived += Output_EventHandle;         //出力
                //process.ErrorDataReceived += OutputError_EventHandle;     //エラー
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--flat-playlist --ignore-errors --no-warnings --no-check-certificate --get-url " + url + " -o \"%(url)s\" ";


                process.Start();

                //process.WaitForExit();
                //Debug.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());


                List<string> urlList = new List<string>();
                StringReader sr = new StringReader(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                string? line = sr.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    //Debug.WriteLine("いいいいいい" + line);
                    urlList.Add(line);

                    line = sr.ReadLine();
                }

                //URLを設定
                foreach (string item in urlList)
                {
                    downloadList_Data.Add(new Data(item));
                }

                process.Close();
            };
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Task.Run(job);//warning CS4014
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Debug.WriteLine("ああああ");
        }
```

###### Data.cs

```cs
        /* ########################### 初期化 ###########################*/
        public Data(string u)
        {
            SetData(u);             
        }

        /* ########################### データを設定 ###########################*/
        private async void SetData(string u)
        {
            url = u;
            Action job = () =>
            {
                process.StartInfo.FileName = "yt-dlp";
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;            //コンソール・ウィンドウを開かない
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;          //シェル機能を使用しない
                process.ErrorDataReceived += this.Output_Error;


                //タイトルを取得                
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = " --no-warnings --get-title " + u + " -o " + "\"%(title)s\"";
                process.OutputDataReceived += SetTitle_EventHandle;

                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();

                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.CancelErrorRead();

                //フォーマットを取得     
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = " --no-warnings --get-title " + u + " -o " + "\"%(title)s\"";
                process.OutputDataReceived -= SetTitle_EventHandle;
                process.OutputDataReceived += SetFormat_EventHandle;

                process.Start();

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();

                process.CancelOutputRead();
                process.CancelErrorRead();

                process.Close();

                Debug.WriteLine("終了: " + getTitle());

                
                form.setCheckBoxList(getTitle());
               
            };
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            Task.Run(job);  //非同期を処理を実行
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
          
        }
```

Comment: 質問に書いてある 2 つの警告の理由が分かればいいのですか？　今までのあなたの話（Teratail での数多くのスレッドを含む）から想像するに、コードを見てデバッグ（もしくは改善点の指摘）をして欲しいとも受け取れますが・・・

Comment: デバッグでありません。目的の動作は実装できたのですがこれは実装として正解なのかどうかを知りたいのです。

Comment: 「目的の動作は実装できた」のであれば、それがあなたにとっての正解ではないのですか。「実装として正解」かどうかなんて議論しても意味ないと思いますけど。あなたにとっての正解は私にとっては不正解かもしれないし、私にとっての正解はあなたにとって不正解かもしれないのですよ。

Comment: ではもう一つの聞きたいのですが正解の場合警告文は何を意味しているのでしょうか？これは同期処理なのでしょうか？

Comment: だから「目的の動作は実装できた」のであれば、それがあなたにとっての正解ではないかと言っているのですが。警告を無視してあなたの目的が果たせるのであれば無視するのが正解では？

Comment: そうなのですか。この警告が何を意味しているか知りたいのですが文章の通りといえばそれまでですがなぜこういった文章なのでしょうか？

Comment: コードのどの行でその警告が出ているのか書いてください。

Comment: Task.Run()部です。

Comment: 手抜きしないで、質問を編集して、分かりやすく、コード上の警告が出る行に「<= ここで CS4014」とか書けないのかな？

Comment: warning CS4014 と warning CS1998 は出る行が違うよね。手抜きのまま終わりにするのかな？　ならば自分は撤退します。

Comment: いえ、二つ発生します。

Comment: warning CS4014 と warning CS1998 は出る行が違うよねと言ったんだけど。コード上の警告が出る行に「<= ここで CS4014」とか書けないのかなと言ったんだけど。聞いてます？

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは質問者と回答者は対等です。[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に則り、けなす言動や敵意のある言葉と捉えられるような言い方は避けてくださるようお願いいたします。

Comment: すいませんでした。以後指摘通り質問文を修正します。自分の見落としが原因でした。

Comment: 質問者さん、その後無言ですが、回答したのでそれに対するフィードバックをタイムリーに返してください。役に立った/立たなかったぐらいはすぐに返せるのでは？ 役に立たなかったならどこがダメかを書くとより期待に近い回答が出てくるかも。とにかく無言は NG です。

Comment: WebSurfer さん、スタック・オーバーフローでは、誰かの回答に対して必ず返事を書かないといけないというようなルールはありません。確かにより質問者さんに合った回答を望むのであれば質問文を洗練させたり回答にコメントしたりすることができますが、必須ではありません（個人的にはやった方がより助かるとは思います）。質問者さんに推奨されているのはチェックマークを押して回答を承認することと、投票をすることくらいです。スタック・オーバーフローは Q&A の wiki のようなもので、質問されてから時間が経って回答が増えることもあります。必ずしも質問者さんのためだけに Q&A を残している訳ではないことをご理解くださいませ。

Comment: nekketsuuu さん> 回答に対するフィードバックを要求するのは Stackoverflow ではルール違反と言ってますか？　そんなバカな話はないと思うのですけど？　要求されて必ず答えなければならないという義務はないのは分かりますが、要求してはいけないなんてことは常識的＆普通に考えてあり得ないと思っているのですが。あと、前のあなたのコメントの「スタック・オーバーフローでは質問者と回答者は対等です」というのは私に対して言っているようですが、それは質問者に対しても言うべき話です。

Comment: @WebSurfer どんなコミュニケーション方法でも「レスを返す」「そしてなるべく早く」が良いのはもちろんですが、ネット上で "タイムリーに" は少し相手に求めすぎな気がします。該当サイト (ページ) だけに一日中かじりついているわけでもないので、2,3日位は待ってみませんか？

Comment: > 2,3日位は待ってみませんか？　←待っていればフィードバックが返ってくるってホントに思ってますか？　そもそもタイムリーに返すというのはマナー的にあたりまえなのですが、言わないと返さない人が多いのですよ。このスレッドのように言っても返って来ませんしね。黙ってマイナス評価をつける人もいるし。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await`しないのであれば、メソッドの定義も`async`としないでください。
`Task.Run()`による非同期処理はasync/awaitでの非同期処理の前によく使われていた方法です。

[async および await を使用した非同期プログラミング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

また`Task.Run()`の後に待つ処理が無い場合は、Taskが終了する前にプログラムが終了する可能性がある＝Taskの完了を保証できないので、警告が出る…ということです。

Comment: > Task.Run()による非同期処理はasync/awaitでの非同期処理の前によく使われていた方法です。　← それはどういう意味でしょう？　async/await が使えるなら Task.Run は使う必要が無いと言ってますか？　もしそういう意味だとすると、それは違うと思うのですが。例えば、同期メソッドしか提供されてないライブラリで、それを別スレッドで実行したい場合、Task.Run を使うということになると思うのですが。

Comment: それはそうですね。質問者さんは、非同期といえばTask.Runであるということ、それと同時に非同期ならasyncで装飾という理解をしているように読めたので、async/awaitについてリンク先を読んで理解してもらえばいいかなと思っただけです。Task.Runは使わなくても済むなら使わない方が良いとは考えています。

Answer (score 0):

質問 1, 2 に対してはコメント欄で書きましたが再掲します。

> １，目的の動作は実装できたのですがこれは実装として正解なのか知りたい。

「目的の動作は実装できた」のであれば、それがあなたにとっての正解ではないのですか。「実装として正解」かどうかなんて議論しても意味ないと思いますけど。私にとっての正解はあなたにとって不正解かもしれないし。

> ２，その場合///部で発生する上記の二つの警告文は無視していいのか知りたい

警告を無視してあなたの目的が果たせるのであれば無視するのが正解だと思います。

実際に動かして試す環境はあなたしか持ってないし、あなたの期待することも詳しくは他人には分からないのだから、質問 1, 2 については上記以上のことは私は言えません。

> ３，Debug.WriteLine()関数を使って処理を確認しました非同期で実行されているのですがなぜ同期処理という警告なのでしょうか？

CS1998 と CS4014 の警告が解せないということですよね。質問者さんのケースで警告は何を言っているかと言うと:

warning CS1998: async 修飾子でメソッドが非同期であると指定するとともに内部で await を使えるようにしたんだよね？　なのに await が使われてないけどいいの？

warning CS4014: Task.Run(job) でメインスレッドとは別のスレッドで job が実行されるようにしているが、await を付与して job が終わるまで待機しなくていいの？

・・・ということだと思います。

上の「いいの？」に対して、質問者さんは問題ないという判断なのですよね。であれば警告なので無視するか、警告を抑制するということになると思います。

質問者さんのケースでは async を削除すれば警告は消えると思います。動作にも影響はないと思います。

ただし、CS4014 については以下のドキュメントに書いてあるように「非同期呼び出しの完了を待つ必要がなく、呼び出されたメソッドで例外が発生しないことが確実である場合に限り、警告を抑制することを検討してください」とのことなので、そのあたりはよく考えた方が良さそうです。

コンパイラの警告 (レベル 1) CS4014
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs4014

もう一つ、勘違いしているかもしれないので念のため書いておきます。async というのはただの修飾子です。メソッドが非同期であると指定するとともに内部で await を使えるようにするものです。async を付与したからと言って非同期になるわけではありません。詳しくは以下のドキュメントを見てください。

async (C# リファレンス)
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async

---

【追記】

もう一つ注意事項を思い出したので書いておきます。

上に「Task.Run(job) でメインスレッドとは別のスレッドで job が実行される」と書きましたが、その別スレッドはバックグラウンドスレッドになります。メインスレッドはフォアグラウンドスレッドになります。

なので、メインスレッドを終了させると job はシャットダウンされます。Task.Run(job) で別スレッドで独自に動いて完了することを期待していると不都合があるかもしれません。

フォアグラウンド スレッドとバックグラウンド スレッド
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads

Comment: 前にもそういうことがあったけど、理由も書かないでマイナス評価を付けた卑怯者は誰？　マイナスは「この回答は役に立たない」ということだが、あなたが思う役に立たない理由を書こう。

Comment: 昔からそういう人は居るようです。いくつかMetaの方で提起していますが賛同する人が出てこないですね。[ヘルプセンター:「マイナス投票する」のヘルプを見易い/見付け易い位置に](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3410/26370), [ヘルプセンター: 「マイナス投票する」の...に代わるものは？の候補追加](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3412/26370), [ヘルプセンター: マイナス投票 に関する記述の整合性・一貫性](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3413/26370) そして質問に対する投票での遥か昔の記事 [質問に対して、反対票を入れる評価基準はありますか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1876/26370)